# Mobile web - best way to youtube video

Tags: mobile-safari, mobile-website

what is the best way to open a video on mobile device?

When I do <a href="rtsp://v1.cache8.c.youtube.com/CjYLENy73wIaLQm48jOBFgMm4BMYESARFEIJbXYtZ29vZ2xlSARSBXdhdGNoYOmUwLWB-O6zSww=/0/0/0/video.3gp">video</a> that works fine on my HTC Touch but on iPhone it complained that link is not valid.

Please enlight.

Thank you,
Tee

Answer (score 0):

Use the embed code provided by YouTube on the video's page, not a link to the actual video file:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/YouTubeLinks/YouTubeLinks.html